# Using stale statistics instead of current ones

Tags: database, postgresql, logging

If I am writing constantly to a database and the following LOG message is displayed will any of the data I am writing by damaged or omitted?

```
LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this will not affect the integrity of data written to the database.

It just means that the statistics collector does not react fast enough, perhaps because of I/O overload.

You can probably get rid of the problem if you set [`stats_temp_directory`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-STATS-TEMP-DIRECTORY) to point to a directory in a RAM file system.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the previous answer, no it will not lose data. But you probably still want to fix the problem.

One possible cause for this problem is that the statistics collector process is bound to an IP:port which is not responding.

In such a case, restarting postgres will fix it.

This problem happened to me when I disabled IPv6 on the server without restarting Postgres. I eventually found a detailed explanation [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/stale-statistics-cause-table-bloat/) (search for "The statistics collector" in the page), but in short:

> PostgreSQL [...] will loop through all the addresses returned [for
> `localhost`], create a UDP socket and test it until it has a socket
> that works.

If the socket it had selected was IPv6 and it is later disabled, it stops working and you get that message in the logs.

You can check to which IP and UDP port the "postmaster" (or "postgres") service is bound with

```
netstat -n -u -p
```

The output is something like this:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47780         127.0.0.1:47780         ESTABLISHED 2824/postmaster
```

or on another host where it is bound to IPv6 ("udp6"):

```
# netstat -n -u -p
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
udp6       0      0 ::1:51761               ::1:51761               ESTABLISHED 1006/postgres
```